# How to get title of images in post content

Tags: images, filters, hooks, the-content

Today I have the function created below using regex that inserts the POST title if the ALT attribute of the image inserted in the content is empty.

But now I want to get the title of the image and not the post. How to make?

```
if( ! ( function_exists( 'add_alt_image_content' ) ) ) {
    function add_alt_image_content( $content ) {

        if ( is_single() && in_the_loop() && is_main_query() ) {

            global $post;

            $image = get_post( $post->ID );
            $image_title = $image->post_title;
    
            $pattern = '~(<img.*? alt=")("[^>]*>)~i';
            $replace = '$1'.$image_title.'$2';
            $content = preg_replace( $pattern, $replace, $content );
            
            return $content;
        }
    } 
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'add_alt_image_content' );
```

Answer (score 0):

just change the $post->ID with get_post_thumbnail_id(), and possibly we can delete also the global $post;

```
if( ! ( function_exists( 'add_alt_image_content' ) ) ) {
    function add_alt_image_content( $content ) {

        if ( is_single() && in_the_loop() && is_main_query() ) {

            global $post;

            $image = get_post(get_post_thumbnail_id());
            $image_title = $image->post_title;
    
            $pattern = '~(<img.*? alt=")("[^>]*>)~i';
            $replace = '$1'.$image_title.'$2';
            $content = preg_replace( $pattern, $replace, $content );
            
            return $content;
        }
    } 
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'add_alt_image_content' );
```

Comment: but get_post_thumbnail is from the featured image. What I need is the name of the title of the other images inserted in the content.

Comment: I had been checking the code and the get_posts(1534) with an image id returns the proper code, and the $image_title gets the image name correctly, the code seems fine, I believe the problem is on the id that is introduced in get_posts()

Comment: But in this case I don't have the specific image ID information, as it will depend on the images inserted in the post's content.

Comment: it's possible to share the code where those images are being loaded, the post content?.

Comment: Maybe the with the function get_the_ID();